# Polymorphism and deep inheritance in JS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymorphism, prototypejs, hierarchy

I'm using the JS [prototype inheritance pattern from Gavin Kistner](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html) and I'm not quite sure why deep inheritance doesn't work for me.

I want C inherits from B inherits from A...

```
Function.prototype.inheritsFrom = function( parentClassOrObject )
{
   if ( parentClassOrObject.constructor == Function )
   {
      //Normal Inheritance
      this.prototype = new parentClassOrObject;
      this.prototype.constructor = this;
      this.prototype.parent = parentClassOrObject.prototype;
   }
   else
   {
      //Pure Virtual Inheritance
      this.prototype = parentClassOrObject;
      this.prototype.constructor = this;
      this.prototype.parent = parentClassOrObject;
   }
   return this;
}

function A() {
   // ...
}
A.prototype.init = function( arg ) {
   // ...
}

function B() {
   A.apply( this, arguments );  // call super constructor
   // ...
}
B.inheritsFrom( A );
B.prototype.init = function( arg ) {
    B.parent.init.call( this, arg );
    // ...
}

function C() {
   B.apply( this, arguments ); // call super constructor
   // ...
}
C.inheritsFrom( B );
C.prototype.init = function( arg ) {
   this.parent.init.call( this, arg );
   // ...
}

var foo = new C();
foo.init( 10 );  

// Throws an exception: infinite call loop.
```

When I call `foo.init()`, I'm actually calling `C.init()`
Inside `C.init()` 'this' is of type C
-> `this.parent.init.call( this, arg )` is actually calling `B.init()`
Inside `B.init()` 'this' is still of type C ( because of `.call(this)`)
-> `this.parent.init.call( this, arg )` is, again, calling `B.init()`

And therefore it goes into an infinite call loop on `B.init()` ...

What am I doing wrong ?
Should I simply rename 'init' to something else for B and C ?  I would rather not, because the current way allows me to call `obj.init()` whether obj is of type A, B or C...

Comment: inheritance like this is just wrong. Classical OO like this should not be hacked into JavaScript. Please use prototypical OO and traits instead

Comment: @Raynos Raynos is right.  Raynos, can you add-in a link to an example you like?

Comment: [TraitsJS](http://traitsjs.org/) is a great library for prototypical OO. Just limiting yourself to only use `Object.create`, `Trait` and only have prototypical inheritance chains one level deep should produce good prototypical OO

Comment: This has been stale for a while, but in the meantime I've learned a bit more and got to agree with Raynos, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `B.parent.init.call( this, arg );` to `B.prototype.parent.init.call( this, arg );`.

Comment: Aaaaah see, this was my problem. It was a typo, this line was actually "this.prototype.parent.init.call( this, arg )".

I changed it to use the class name instead of "this", and added '.prototype' as you suggested and it works perfectly !  Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but I have been doing some work with JavaScript inheritance recently. If you want to go the classical route, I can really recommend **[JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/)**; it's a library that makes classes really easy.

If you can, you should avoid using the library, but if you don't want to deal with the headache of JavaScript inheritance/prototyping, I can recommend JS.Class.

Comment: You should indeed avoid all classical OO emulation. I would also recommend [traitsJS](http://traitsjs.org/) as prototypical OO alternative